# HTML/CSS Div and Background Image

Tags: css, image, html, background

I have a very large image. I want to use this image as the background of my website. I would also like for this image to stretch and fit different browser window sizes.

This is the solution I have come up with. (I put it on jFiddle to make it easier for you guys to read).

http://jsfiddle.net/sGyax/

```
.bg{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -5000;}

<body>
<div id="background">
    <img src="background/001.JPG" class="bg"/>
</div>
</body>
```

Is there anyway for me to do this without using IMG tag in my HTML? It interferes with the rest of my layout.

Comment: you could just set the body background to background/001.jpg instead of the div background and use css3 to set the background-size:cover

Comment: That does work, but it is not as effective as what I had before. When you play with the window size it does not morph with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in IE9/10 and current Firefox, Opera and Chrome:

```
html{
    background: url(background/001.JPG) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='background/001.JPG',     sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='background/001.JPG', sizingMethod='scale');
}
```

Comment: the progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader filter should solve this for preIE9 versions of IE but to be honest I don't have an IE8 machine available to test (this was the code I had on an old client site and IIRC it did work on IE8)

Comment: thanks for edit Matt - good catch (must have borked it when I was spacing for layout in)

Answer (score 1):

Make it a [background image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-image) (see example below) instead of an image with a huge negative z-index, and consider using the CSS3 [backgound-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size) property for covering the entire page.

```
background-image: url(background/001.JPG)
```

Comment: This does not work. It makes the image the background but does not fit the browser. I added the option to cover and no-repeat, but it does not work as effectively as what I had before it. When you play with the window size... it does not morph with it.